# JQuery call replace method after load method

Tags: jquery

I want to use this instuction after load page (using .load method)

```
this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(/\bok\b/g, '<img src="ok.png" alt="good word"/>')
```

i want to use it for all `<p>` who haves `class="special"` after page was loaded.

how to do this ?

Thank's

Comment: The answers below are correct for the information you have provided. If they do not work, then please edit your question with a Short, Self-contained Example (http://sscce.org/) so that we may better help.

Answer (score 0):

If it is in page load then

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('p.special').html(function(idx, html){
        return html.replace(/\bok\b/g, '<img src="ok.png" alt="good word"/>')
    })
})
```

If it is using dynamic element loading using `.load()`, then in the load callback you can add the `$('p.special').html(...)`